# What is CustomDataType?

Tags: metadata-api

What is **CustomDataType** and how to use it? And how to create it directly in org?

I can't find any description and don't see any mention about it in my organization.

There is such type in Metadata API and docs say that I can deploy it (without further information).

Link to docs where it's described would be also a great answer to my question.

**UPDATE**

In docs it's mentioned [here Running Tests in a Deployment](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm) and [here Metadata Field Types](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_field_types.htm)

Thank you.

Comment: "There is such type in Metadata API and docs say that I can deploy it (without further information)." can you please provide the link where this is mentioned? probably that would help us understand what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: I updated question and provided two links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ..

CustomDataType is for a yet-unreleased feature (as of V33) wherein admins can define their own datatypes in addition to the text, decimal, boolean, etc.  One use case for this is a picklistType that you want to share the picklist entries across multiple sobjects.

Feature is in pilot - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&language=en_US